# CMTime doesn't seek AVPlayer to correct time

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `AVPlayer` that I want to begin playing at the specific time of `11.593` seconds. I have this number in milliseconds retrieved from a URL string, converted to a `Double`, then to a `CMTime` like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/video?s=11593
```

Extract the `11593` as a `String` -> convert to `Double` `11593.0`.

Then I convert to a `CMTime`:

```
let time = CMTime(seconds: milliseconds, 
       preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_MSEC))
```

Then I tell the `AVPlayer` to seek:

```
player.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

But the player always seeks to `25.88` seconds. Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire use of `CMTime(seconds:preferredTimescale:)` is wrong. The first argument should be a number of seconds (hence the name, `seconds:`), not a number of milliseconds; and the second argument should be a reasonable timescale, such as 600.

Comment: Changed it to seconds and it worked. Then what exactly is NSEC_PER_MSEC for then if that's not for milliseconds?

Comment: It is for milliseconds. You would use it to turn your seconds into milliseconds, not to set the timescale. You seem to think the `preferredTimescale` affects the `seconds` in some way. It doesn't.

Comment: Apple use `NSEC_PER_SEC` as their `CMTime` timescale for seconds, therefore I thought I could use the MSEC for the milliseconds timescale. Obviously not...

Comment: You can use whatever you like for the timescale, but whatever you use does not magically turn milliseconds into seconds. You may be confusing this method with `init(value:timescale:)`, which works in a completely different way: there, the values are numerator and denominator of a fraction. But not here.